# SYMFONY KnpMenuBundle - Where can I find more insight about "others rendering options"?

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I am having a look at the doc of KnpMenuBundle for SYMFONY,

In the part:
[KNPMENU others rendering options](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/doc/01-Basic-Menus.markdown#other-rendering-options); It lists a bunch of options that can be used when rendering the menu thru a TWIG file like this:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', {'depth': 2, 'currentAsLink': false}) }}
{{ knp_menu_render(menuItem) }}
```

I am wondering what those options do, I am especially wondering about the "currentAsLink" one. I can't find any link where those options have been detailed. Does anyone have **more explanation about those functionalities**?

Comment: You may find the answer in the source code: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=currentAsLink

Comment: Ok in the code it says a comment: "currentAsLink: whether the current item should be a link", I try to pass {currentAsLink: false} in the knp_menu_render(...) to see if what is a <a> with attribute "href" changes to something else (what I get if currentAsLink is default "true"). It doesn't change anything. Maybe my  interpretation of the comment in the code is not correct.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after having changed the option's value? According to the Twig file, it should be rendered as a `<span>` instead of `<a>`. It's possible that the function is not implemented.

Comment: I did another try after a "php bin/console cache:clear" and still have the <a> instead of the <span>. I do some workaround with some JS on the frontend to achieve what I want. The problem I have with <a> is that it does not reload the page if it is already on the DOM, which is probably efficient but has some unwanted side effect -like creating a page with an "id" that already exists which lead to some confusion when I do some JS on that "id" value latter on.

Comment: @A.L how do you highlight <span> and <a> in your comment?

Comment: See code formatting in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting (or click on *help* under the *Add comment* button)